# Tkinter text-widget insertion of images

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I made a text widget to write questions. I want to insert images when add image button is pressed. How can I do that? When I choose another image the first one is deleted. Right now I am able to add one image using the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x520+0+0')
global img
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="quiz.gif")
def add_img():
    T.image_create(tk.INSERT, image=img)
tk.Button(root, text="Add Image", font=('Verdana',8), 
command=add_img).place(x=690, y=0)
T = tk.Text(root, width=65, height=17, padx=10, pady=10, font=('Verdana', 
14), wrap='word')
T.place(x=0, y=0)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to add different images when chosen using tk-listbox.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Creating a second image is no different then creating the first. It's unclear what you're asking about. Also, you mention a listbox but your code doesn't have a listbox.

Comment: My question is: is it necessary to declare variable for all available images. Because when I use the same variable for the second image the first one get removed. Is it possible to create a list box taking all image files using glob.glob('*.gif') and create that image.

Comment: Yes I can create another variable img... and declare it. Is there a way that I just change the file. img = tk.PhotoImage(file=variable). I have not used the listbox for above example but is there a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

I used dictionary to solve the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk, glob
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x520+0+0')
Images = {}
for infile in glob.glob('*.gif'):
    img = infile[:-4]
    if img not in Images:
        Images[img] = tk.PhotoImage(file=infile)
def add_img():
    global listbox
    listbox = tk.Listbox(root, font=('Verdana',9), width=12)
    listbox.place(x=60,y=2)
    for infile in glob.glob('*.gif'):
        listbox.insert(tk.END, infile[:-4])
    listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelet)
def CurSelet(event):
    fn = listbox.get(tk.ANCHOR)
    listbox.destroy()
    T.image_create(tk.INSERT, image=Images[fn])
tk.Button(root, text="Add Image", font=('Verdana',8), 
command=add_img).place(x=690,y=0)
T = tk.Text(root, width=65, height=17, padx=10, pady=10, font=('Verdana', 
14), wrap='word')
T.place(x=0, y=50)
root.mainloop()
```